# Replacing values in a string using c#

Tags: c#

I have a php example and am trying to replicate this in c#.  What is the best way to do so? I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

```
$string = 'The event will take place between :start and :end';

$replaced = preg_replace_array('/:[a-z_]+/', ['8:30', '9:00'], $string);
```

It fills in the :start and :end with the times in the array.

Answer (score 2):

No need of regex you can just you format

```
String.Format("The event will take place between {0} and {1}", "8:30", "9:00");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use either **Composite formatting** or **String interpolation** feature.

`String.Format` makes use of the composite formatting feature:

```
// Composite formatting:
var string = "The event will take place between {0} and {1}";
var replaced = String.Format(string, "8:30", "9:00");
```

Or use `$` at the beginning of your string and pass the parameters into it very easily:

```
// String interpolation:
var replaced = $"The event will take place between {"8:30"} and {"9:00"}";
```

**String interpolation** provides a more readable and convenient syntax to create formatted strings than a string composite formatting feature.

Visit the following links for more information:

[1. String.Format Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

[2. $ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)